# Redirect a controller to main index

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, indexing, routes

I have a controller I am using for redirects called `redirect.php`. This controller has a single `_remap($method)`.

This `_remap` method works by attributing any URI string after the redirect controller back into the controller. For example, a request to `http://mysite.com/redirect/sometext` would send the request back to `http://mysite.com/redirect`

This is the behavior I want, but how I would make this happen at the `index level` so instead of having to type `http://mysite.com/redirect/sometext` , I could type `http://mysite.com/sometext` and get the same behavior. This is challenging because `Index.php` is used by CodeIgniter so I can't put the `_remap` method here. As, I'm not super familiar with routes and .htaccess any help would be appreciated to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to go the routes way, you would make a route for each controller you have, aka controller `somepage` would have a route `$route["somepage"] = "somepage";`, then after all of them (at the very bottom of the routes).  Routes work by finding the first matching regex and then using it, so to make sure all of your controllers work, and only catch regular text, you need each of these rules.
Then we make the 'default' rule, this would run for everything that didn't get caught in a previous route check.  Something like `$route["(.*)"] = 'redirect/index/$1';`.  This would redirect you to the controller `redirect`, with the first uri segment (segment 3) being the `sometext` in your example above.  Do note that this will also run for 404 pages, it would run for **everything** that isn't defined in the above rules.

I don't see a point in this, if I were you I would just send it to the redirect controller, it would make things a bit less messy, but there is of course a way as shown above.

Comment: Iv'e got a bit of a special use case where I need to get rid of the redirect segment but retain it's functionality. I'll try your suggestion shortly.

Comment: excellent, thanks. I just got around to testing. I was migrating to a new testing server and had an issue that was preventing me from trying this out. Works perfectly.